# super() в конструкторе класса

Tags: javascript, reactjs, конструктор

Нужно создать класс, содержащий и обрабатывающий информацию о li-шке. Что я не так делаю? Браузер после запуска исходников через webpack ругается:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
 at _inherits (index.js:22398)
 at index.js:22407
 at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:22479)
 at __webpack_require__ (index.js:20)
 at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:9755)
 at __webpack_require__ (index.js:20)
 at module.exports (index.js:63)
 at index.js:66
```

Вот мой код:

```
class Input extends React.Component () {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lies : [],
            userInput : "",
            divStyle : {
                width : 460,
                margin : "auto",
                backgroundColor : "lightgrey"
            }
        }
    }

    /.../ Здесь пропущены функции связанные с imputom и сохранением пользовательской информации 

        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange = {refreshInput} type = 'text'></input>
                <button onClick = {crecaeNote}></button>
                <br/>
                <ul>
                    {lies}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: зачем тут круглые скобки? `extends React.Component ()`?

Comment: @ torokhkun Версия react: 3.10.10

Comment: @Grundy, ответы - в ответы...

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне кажется это опечатка просто :-)

Comment: @Grundy, зря кажется))

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну ок, добавил ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Проблема в `()` ➞ `class Input extends React.Component () {`

---

[Согласно спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-class-definitions) между именем класса и телом класса может располагаться [ClassHeritage](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-ClassHeritage)

```
ClassHeritage[Yield, Await]:
    extends LeftHandSideExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
```

где *LeftHandSideExpression* - почти любое выражение.

В итоге, идет попытка наследования не от `React.Component`, а от того, что вернет вызов [`React.Component()`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/ae430b79139777b74167b124719b3dc311aa5294/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactBaseClasses.js#L23), судя по всему он возвращает `undefined` и получается закономерная ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была связана ко скобками. `React.Component ()` - было, а нужно `React.Component`